# change column in pre-selected elements in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have a dataframe with three different columns, like shown in the example above (*df*).
The goal of this task is to replace the first element of the column **2** by a np.nan, everytime the letter in the column **1** changes. Since the database under study is very big, it cannot be used a for loop. Also every solution that involves a shift is excluded because it is too slow.

I believe the easiest way is to use the *groupby* and the *head* method, however I don't know how to replace in the original dataframe.

Examples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A','Z',1.11],['B','Z',2.1],['C','Z',3.1],['D', 'X', 2.1], ['E','X',4.3],['E', 'X', 2.1], ['F','X',4.3]])
```

[image]

to select the elements that we want to change, we can do the following:

```
df.groupby(by=1).head(1)[2] = np.nan
```

However in the original dataframe nothing changes.
The goal is to obtain the following:

[image]

### Edit:

Based on comments, we won't `df[1]` returning to a group already seen, e.g. `['Z', 'Z', 'X', 'Z']` is not possible.

Comment: Is column `1` sorted, e.g. is `['Z', 'Z', 'X', 'Z']` possible?

Comment: no, it is not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Using `mask` and `shift`

```
df[2] = df[2].mask(df[1].ne(df[1].shift(1)))
```

#### Using a `masked_array`:

```
df[2] = np.ma.masked_array(df[2], df[1].ne(df[1].shift(1))).filled(np.nan)
# array([nan, 2.1, 3.1, nan, 4.3, 2.1, 4.3])
```

#### Using `np.roll` and `loc`:

```
a = df[1].values
df.loc[np.roll(a, 1)!=a, 2] = np.nan
```

```
   0  1    2
0  A  Z  NaN
1  B  Z  2.1
2  C  Z  3.1
3  D  X  NaN
4  E  X  4.3
5  E  X  2.1
6  F  X  4.3
```

Comment: Ok nice with timings but can you add duplicated?

Comment: Strangely, I found `np.where(df[1].duplicated(), df[2], np.nan)` fastest.

Comment: Yep, found that, but would give incorrect results if a value appears more than once.  There has to be a check for every time the value changes

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for a vectorised conditional assignment. This assumes `df[1]` is already sorted.

```
df[2] = np.where(df[1].duplicated(), df[2], np.nan)
```

If sorting cannot be assumed:

```
df[2] = np.where(df[1] != df[1].shift(), np.nan, df[2])
```

Result:

```
   0  1    2
0  A  Z  NaN
1  B  Z  2.1
2  C  Z  3.1
3  D  X  NaN
4  E  X  4.3
5  E  X  2.1
6  F  X  4.3
```

The equivalent logic can be applied using [`pd.DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html).

Answer (score 5):

Using

```
df[2].mask(df.groupby(1).cumcount().eq(0))
Out[41]: 
0    NaN
1    2.1
2    3.1
3    NaN
4    4.3
5    2.1
6    4.3
Name: 2, dtype: float64

#df[2] = df[2].mask(df.groupby(1).cumcount().eq(0))
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Built for speed

```
a = df[1].values
b = np.flatnonzero(np.append(True, a[1:] != a[:-1]))
df[2].values[b] = np.nan

df

   0  1    2
0  A  Z  NaN
1  B  Z  2.1
2  C  Z  3.1
3  D  X  NaN
4  E  X  4.3
5  E  X  2.1
6  F  X  4.3
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get the index from your groupby and use it as a mask with `.loc`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A','Z',1.11],
    ['B','Z',2.1],
    ['C','Z',3.1],
    ['D', 'X', 2.1], 
    ['E','X',4.3],
    ['E', 'X', 2.1], 
    ['F','X',4.3]
])

m = df.groupby(by=1).head(1).index
df.loc[m,2] = np.nan

print(df)
```

---

**OR** you could use duplicated() instead. This should be faster.

```
m = ~df[1].duplicated()
df.loc[m, 2] = np.nan
```

returns:

```
   0  1    2
0  A  Z  NaN
1  B  Z  2.1
2  C  Z  3.1
3  D  X  NaN
4  E  X  4.3
5  E  X  2.1
6  F  X  4.3
```

Comment: Isn't the .loc a slow solution?

Comment: @NunodeSousa nope, loc is a selector. Loc itself is not a slow solution. Loc is one of the most powerful things in pandas, I think most of the community can agree on that.